# Can Terraria iOS players play with PC players?

Tags: steam, terraria, terraria-mobile, windows

I don't play Terraria much, but my little brother saw me playing on my PC and said he wanted to try. I let him, and he loved it. Once I told him we could play together, he got extremely happy and now I'm trying to figure it out, but can't. I looked around and I'm getting tons of answers, all of which are very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

No, consoles and mobile devices can't play together with PC, because they're on different versions of the game and have different content.